# El expression not giving desired result

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces, el, jsf-1.2

I'm using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces in my application. When I try to access the header in the rich panel I get an exception and I cannot figure it out.

```
<c:forEach var="comp" items="${components.component.components}">

    <rich:panel header="${comp.key}"></rich:panel>
```

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /gencom.jsp(19,5) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute header does not accept any expressions
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
    at at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
```

Added taglib like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsf/core"; prefix="f"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsf/html"; prefix="h"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>;
<%@ taglib uri="richfaces.org/a4j"; prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="richfaces.org/rich"; prefix="rich"%>
```

Comment: What `taglib` you are using ? Can you add more JSF page code

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>

Comment: @SubodhJoshi these are the tags I am using

Comment: Can you add all the imports in your JSP in the question ?

Comment: Which version of JSTL you are using? Read this http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-reference-and-use-jstl-in-your-web-application/

Comment: The error is clear: you're not allowed to pass a dynamic expression for the `header` attribute - only static values allowed